# How to use countif in DAX?

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

I have several table and the value of the table is T or blank. I would like to count the total of column
if table A and Table B has value= T then it counts 1
if table C and table D has value = T then it count 1
my expectation to count the total of columns A to D with that pair condition.
[image]

Anyone can give ide please, I am really new with DAX thank you.

Comment: Can you add table samples and result sample? Not clear what do you mean by `Table has value`

Comment: @Mik I added the table sample. thank you

Comment: So, it's different columns of one table? and do you want to check pairs for exact value or you want to count just pairs for all values?

Comment: how do you want to count 1-st row in the sample as 1 or 2? It would be nice if you add count results for each row for the sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you sample the measure can looks like this:

If you want to count pairs for exact value

```
Countrows(
    Filter(
        tbl
        ,[Table A]= "T" && [Table B]="T"
           ||  
         [Table C]="T" && [Table D]="T" 
    )
)

-- "&&" has a higher priority then "||", so "&&" evaluates first
```

The filter() returns a filtered table. The function checks each row in the table, if expression evaluated as TRUE then the row remains.

If you want to count any pair values

```
Countrows(
    Filter(
        tbl
        ,[Table A]=[Table B] || [Table C]=[Table D] 
    )
)
```